# Ubuntu logs in into blank purple screen, please help

Tags: boot, nvidia

MODEL : Asus R541UJ
CPU : i5 7200U
RAM : 8GB DDR4
GPU : nvidia geforce 920m

I am new to Ubuntu, it worked fine when I used it in my virtual box but now when I am trying to natively install it , it's giving me this blank purple screen after logging in.
I tried the nomodeset , dis_ucode_ldr and also updated the firmware of my BIOS but none of them worked, it's been 3 days and I am yet to break through this problem , please help. I also tried installing pop os , mint , elementary OS, but none of them worked in case of pop os, the installer was stuck at one point and didn't make any progress, in case of mint and elementary it showed that the system doesn't have any free space.

Answer (score 0):

When booting, press `Esc` to enter Grub Menu!
Select Ubuntu and press `e` to edit boot parameters.
Look for `quiet splash` and after that, add `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau`.
Then press `F10` to boot.
It should work, if it does, go to the `Additional Drivers` app and install Nvidia drivers from there.

I have an Omen 15, with Intel CPU and Nvidia 1050 Ti, I suspect the issue is with the default drivers, that fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but even now, I get the purple albeit now my cursor is visible but the purple screen still persists.